# Five pills problem from exercises based on Feynman's lectures

Tags: probability, summation, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, coupon-collector

[image]
I have some questions about the solution to the five pills problem which is part of the list of exercises based on Feynman's lectures. [image: form]

In the solution above m is the number of types of pills and there are n pills of each type for a total of mn pills. K is the number of pills drawn without replacement.

I understand how the principle of inclusion exclusion was used to find L(m,n,k) but am unsure how in the above solution the expression for O(m,n,k) was arrived at. Also, how can it be valid if in the summation j ranges from 0 to m and j-m-1 is negative for these values of j?

Comment: Hello. As stated at The Feynman Lectures website, the exercises posted there include "other physics and math problems of interest" besides   those "based on Feynman's Lectures", as you write above. This particular problem has nothing to do with Feynman's lectures, per se. It was given to me personally by Matthew Sands, one of the coauthors of The Feynman Lectures on Physics, and the solution you quote above is my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are altogether $\binom{mn}k$ combinations of $k$ pills, and $L(m,n,k)$ of them lack at least one pill type, so $\binom{mn}k-L(m,n,k)$ of them contain all types. And

$$\begin{align*}
\binom{mn}k&-L(m,n,k)\\
&=\binom{mn}k-\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j-1}\binom{m}j\binom{mn-jn}k\\
&=(-1)^0\binom{m}0\binom{mn-0\cdot n}k-\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^{j-1}\binom{m}j\binom{mn-jn}k\\
&=(-1)^0\binom{m}0\binom{mn-0\cdot n}k+\sum_{j=1}^m(-1)^j\binom{m}j\binom{mn-jn}k\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m(-1)^j\binom{m}j\binom{(m-j)n}k\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{j-m-1}j\binom{(m-j)n}k
\end{align*}$$

by virtue of the [identity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Negated_Upper_Index_of_Binomial_Coefficient)

$$\binom{r}k=(-1)^k\binom{k-r-1}k$$

(with the factor of $(-1)^k$ brought over to the other side).

The binomial coefficient $\binom{r}k$ is defined for all real (and even complex) numbers $r$ and integers $k$ as follows:

$$\binom{r}k=\begin{cases}
\frac{r^{\underline{k}}}{k!},&\text{if }k\ge 0\\
0,&\text{if }k<0\,,
\end{cases}$$

where

$$r^{\underline{k}}=r(r-1)\ldots(r-k+1)=\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}(r-i)$$

is a [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials). Thus, negative values of $j-m-1$ are not a problem. In fact you can see that $(j-m-1)^{\underline{j}}$ is a product of $j$ negative numbers and so is negative when $j$ is odd and positive when $j$ is even, just like $(-1)^j$.

Comment: In the summation for L(m,n,k) , shouldn't we let j go from 1 through  m-1 instead of m , since the latter would include the case where we have to choose k objects from a total of 0 objects  which doesn't  make any sense?

Comment: @AdNazir: It makes perfectly good sense: if $k>0$, there are clearly $0$ ways to choose $k$ objects from the empty set, and the $j=m$ term is simply $0$. If $k=0$, then $\binom{mn}k=1=L(m,n,k)$, and it’s easy to check that my summation for $L(m,n,k)$ correctly gives $L(m,n,0)=1$.

Comment: k=0 case isn't a problem.  But if j=m , we're  basically  asking in how many ways can we pick k objects from an empty set. Physically it makes sense that the answer  should be zero. But if we use the formula for n choose k , we get 1/[(k!)*(-k!)] and I don't see what factorial of a negative integer means.

Comment: @AdNazir: If $k\ge 0$, $\binom0k=\frac{0^{\underline{k}}}{k!}$. If $k>0$, this is $\frac0{k!}=0$, and if $k=0$, it’s $\frac11=1$, since $0^{\underline 0}=0!=1$.

Comment: Thanks. I think I need to think about it a bit more but it makes some sense now. It is a matter of definitions and base case and using recurrence relations, is it not?

Comment: Also, could you please share a piece of python code to empirically check/verify the answer for general m and n?

Comment: @AdNazir: I can’t help with the code, I’m afraid: I’ve not done any serious programming in almost 50 years. The fact that we can let the index run all the way to $m$ is really just a consequence of the definition of $\binom{r}k$.

Answer (score 3):

I am going to answer the question, "how can it be valid" in an anecdotal way, which applies to my solution as a whole, and not just the one step quoted here by RobPratt.

Matthew Sands, coauthor of The Feynman Lectures on Physics, posed the "five pills" problem to me, on (as I recall) my 2nd or 3rd visit to his home in Santa Cruz, California in 2002. He was, in fact, at the time, taking one each of 5 types of pills a day, inadvertently conducting the experiment described in the exercise, and he had noticed that on the first day of each month (when there were ~150 pills in the bottle) he had to spill out "about 10" pills - twice as many as he needed to take - before he got one of each of the five types, and wondered why that was so. This was a problem I worked on occassionally over a couple of years. My first attempt used questionable methods of approximation that resulted in an answer of 8, which Matt was very displeased with, since it disagreed with his experimental observations! Then I decided to solve the problem numerically, using brute force, by calculating the length and probability of every possible sequence of pills that included at least one of each type! That way I would at least know what the answer *should* be. After that I thought about it occasionally during my early morning dog walks, until one day it dawned on me how to solve it exactly. When I had made the calculation using my exact solution, it matched my numerical approximation to about 20 decimal places, so I figured I must have got it right both times (otherwise such an exact match from two entirely different ways of calculating the answer would be extremely unlikely), and I let Matt know the result of his experiment should be "about 11," which he seemed happier with. Anyway... that was how I validated my solution(s) to this problem.

Comment: Could you please share a piece of python code to empirically check/verify  the answer?

Comment: I have provided a mathematical proof of the general case and a Mathematica document that verifies it. I also wrote a program in 'C' that makes a numerical 'brute force' calculation of the answer in special cases - I did that first before solving the general case. But you can not prove the general case numerically, only special cases. I don't have a piece of python code for calculating special cases, nor is one needed since the general case is proven, and the latter is more precise since it does not suffer from rounding errors.

Comment: I saw your proof. It's so beautifully done! But I was hoping to see it in action through computer simulation. I don't know much about computer programming.  I don't even know how to run that Mathematica document. Could you give instructions if it isn't too much trouble?

Comment: You need to know how to use Mathematica for it to be useful (you also need a license). However, my Mathematica code is not a simulation, it's a calculation based on first principles. You can verify it is correct "by hand" with simple cases, to make sure it gets those right, but for more complex cases, which would be too onerous to work out by hand, you need something else, and I have written such code in 'C', which I can share with you, but if you're not a programmer I'm not sure how much it will help. This is code I wrote for myself 19 years ago and I am not offering it with support.

Comment: can I use excel for the calculation of the expectation which comes around 11? I'm having trouble opening that .nb file. I would like  to know the answer if I have 7 instead of 5 pills for the same 30 days. Must be some fraction with humongous numerator and denominator but I don't know until I see.